# Popup message after redirect OR message after user visits from a particular site

Tags: php, redirect, popup

I'd like to show a popup welcome message AFTER a visitor has been redirected from my old site to the new one.

I'm going to set up the old site with 301 redirects to the new content - and only people coming from the old site should see the welcome message. Users who access the new site directly should not see the message.

I know that I can set up a message before redirect on the old site - but I currently only have access to my client's new site.

I can't find anything anywhere about doing something like this. Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do popup on new site for 301 redirected users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332270/how-to-do-popup-on-new-site-for-301-redirected-users)

Comment: You could try `document.referrer` in javascript.

Comment: It should be possible in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) to check wether the person has been redirected through the old site and not directly. If someone has been redirected through the old site, then show:

```
alert("Welcome");
```

Use:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['...'])){
    //your message
}
```

to check it. Of course if you dont know about **Sessions**, I suggest you read the documentation about it first.

I am using sessions to check wether a person has been logged in before coming to the profile page of mine. Same idea in your case.